# Differences b/w "internal" and "externa" in systemRDL register component property

Tags: specifications

I am confused about "internal" and "external" in systemRDL register component property usage. from SystemRDL 2.0 reference manual, it says:

```
Registers can be instantiated in three forms.
    — **internal** implies all register logic is created **by the SystemRDL compiler** for the instantiation (the default form).
    — **external** signifies the register/memory is implemented by the designer and the interface is inferred from instantiation.
```

how to understand them? I understand this property will impact RTL module generation from an RD file

my confused point is "systemRDL compiler" statement in "internal" part description. if we say systemRDL compiler is to interpret rd file and put all related properties into a plain database, user can define customized generator base on these plain database, so seems like these "internal" and "external" keyword will be only used when we write generator for RTL register module part, is my understanding correct?

any guidance to define "internal" and "external" for register in RD file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct. The `internal` and `internal` component modifiers are there to influence the output of the RTL generator.
By default, registers, regfiles, and fields are internal, so they would be included in the output of a RTL generator.
If you mark a component as external, you are signalling to the compiler that you want to define the implementation of the register/field/etc yourself. The compiler would then provide some form of interface for you to implement the component externally, but still have it be part of the address space of the parent being exported to RTL.

Worth mentioning that `addrmap` components are implicitly external by default since they are intended to describe a physical boundary between RTL components.

Comment: thanks, Alex. 
Yes, addrmap will be implemented with physical boundary, while regfile wont' need this.

Comment: Alex, I don't have enough reputation to give your answer a vote, sry about that